# Gideros event showing as null after being triggered

Tags: mobile, lua, gideros

I have got Dispatched events in my gideros game. What im not certain of, is that when i try access the event (object triggered) it returns a table that has a length of 0.

I have a letter class as below:

```
GridLetter = gideros.class(Sprite)

function GridLetter:init(letter)

    self.image = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("GridLetters/"..letter.."Grid.png"))
    self.image:setAnchorPoint(0.5, 0.5)
    self.focus = false
    self:updateVisualState(true)
    self:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_DOWN, self.onMouseDown, self)
end

function GridLetter:onMouseDown(event)
    if self:hitTestPoint(event.x, event.y) then
        self.focus = true
        self:dispatchEvent(Event.new("GridLetterDown"))
        event:stopPropagation()
    end
end

function GridLetter:updateVisualState(state)
    if state then
        self:addChild(self.image)
    end
end
```

The code that implements this class is below:

```
grid = Core.class(Sprite)

local letterArr = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","u","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"}
local gridboard = {{},{},{},{}}

local letterBoxArr = {{},{},{},{}}
local letterBox

function grid:init(params)

    local widthOfSingle = (application:getContentWidth() / 4)
    for rowCount = 1,4 do
        for colCount = 1,4 do
            rand = math.random(1, 26)
            gridboard[rowCount][colCount] = letterArr[rand]
        end
    end

    for rowCount = 1,4 do
        for colCount = 1,4 do
            letterBox = GridLetter.new(gridboard[rowCount][colCount])
            letterBoxArr[rowCount][colCount] = {letterBoxItem=letterBox}
            letterBoxArr[rowCount][colCount].letterBoxItem:setPosition(((widthOfSingle * colCount) - (widthOfSingle / 2)), 100 * rowCount)
            letterBoxArr[rowCount][colCount].letterBoxItem.letter = gridboard[rowCount][colCount];
            letterBoxArr[rowCount][colCount].letterBoxItem:addEventListener("GridLetterDown", LetterDown, self)
            self:addChild(letterBoxArr[rowCount][colCount].letterBoxItem)
        end
    end
end

function LetterDown(event)
    print(event.target.letter)
end
```

When i click on one of these image, the event is fired and code does run under the LetterDown event, but when trying to access the event parameter, it returns:

```
grid.lua:32: attempt to index field 'target' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    grid.lua:32: in function <grid.lua:31>
    GridLetter.lua:15: in function <GridLetter.lua:12>
```

any idea or workarounds?

When replacing:

```
print(event.target.letter)
```

to

```
print(event.x)
```

It prints nil.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Regards,
Warren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it.. Someone on gideros forums helped me out, thanks to Advert as well.

So in my onMouseDown event i was assigning the .letter on the general event. So creating a local var and assigning it the event before dispatching it, the variable then keeps my assigned letter.

Hope this helps others in future!

`function GridLetter:onMouseDown(event)
       if self:hitTestPoint(event.x, event.y) then
          self.focus = true
          local e = Event.new("GridLetterDown")
          e.letter = self.letter
          self:dispatchEvent(e)
          event:stopPropagation()
       end
    end`

Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer (I'd comment, but that strangely requires rep).

The error you're getting is because in `event`, there's nothing in the `target` field.

You could find out what's in the table by looping over it (or by using a pretty table print function, if glideros defines one/you define one yourself):

```
for k, v in pairs(target) do print(k, v) end
```

If you're not sure if `target` will exist all the time, you can also do something like this:

```
print(not event.target and "event.target does not exist" or event.target.letter)
```

You can read about the `A and B or C` construct here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator

Edit: Assuming that the event you receive fires with a GridLetter object, you are not setting `self.letter` to anything. Perhaps setting the field will help:

```
function GridLetter:init(letter)
    self.letter = letter -- Forgot this?
    self.image = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("GridLetters/"..letter.."Grid.png"))
    self.image:setAnchorPoint(0.5, 0.5)
    self.focus = false
    self:updateVisualState(true)
    self:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_DOWN, self.onMouseDown, self)
end
```

Comment: So i added self.letter = letter to the init method. But it still does not have data. Returns nil. The strange thing is that even the x and y coordinates return nil. Is it anything to do with maybe how i'm linking the events? Should i be using a different way to call events or is this acceptable?

Comment: Ok, I've looked at the documentation a bit. Seems like this is the problem: `self:dispatchEvent(Event.new("GridLetterDown"))` There's no data passed to that event. 
Something like `local ev = Event.new("GridLetterDown"); ev.letter = letter; ev.x = event.x, ev.y = event.y; ev.target = self; self:dispatchEvent(ev)`
I think this should work -- but I can't say for sure, since I'm not familiar with Gideros! :)

Comment: Thanks Advert, I will have a look into your solution today and get back to you on whether it works or not. Thank you for you kind help thus far.

Comment: Advert i would mark yours as answer but it is only a comment thank you though, you were spot on!